# Modificar registro en codigo en c++ desde linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++, linux-mint

Buenas amigos no puedo completar esta parte de mi código, es de modificar un archivo y de texto y cuando le digo el nombre a buscar se forma un bucle infinito, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Estoy intentando hacer una agenda de contactos orientada a objetos en c++
y pues he tenido mis dificultes, aunque yo pienso que ahora nomas falta, este bloque y el de eliminar, que luego lo subiré
Por favor necesito su ayuda, me he trabado bastante y me borra los txt

```
  void modifyrecord(){
  system("cls||clear"); //limpiar pantalla
  string nombre1;   
  struct person person; //da una instancia a la estructura
  ifstream leer; //referencia para lee
  fstream temp; //referencia para un archivo temporal   
  leer.open("project.txt");//abre fichero original
  temp.open("Temp.txt");//abrimos el temporal tambn
  leer>>person.name>>person.address>>person.father_name>>person.mother_name>>person.mobile_number>>person.sex>>person.mail>>person.citision_no;
  //cout << leer;
  bool encontrado=false;
  cout<<"Ingrese clave a modificar"<<endl;
  cin>>nombre1;
  while(!leer.eof())
{
    leer >> person.name
         >> person.address
         >> person.father_name
         >> person.mother_name
         >> person.mobile_number
         >> person.sex
         >> person.mail
         >> person.citision_no;

    cout<< person.name;
    if(person.name == nombre1)
        {
          encontrado=true;
          encontrado=true;
            cout << "Nombre: " << person.name << endl;
            cout << "Direccion: " << person.address << endl;
            cout << "Apellid Paterno: " << person.father_name << endl;
            cout << "Apellido Materno: " << person.mother_name << endl;
            cout << "Num. de telefono: " << person.mobile_number << endl;
            cout << "Sexo: " << person.sex << endl;
            cout << "e-mail: " << person.mail << endl;
            cout << "Num. ciudadano: " << person.citision_no << endl;
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"Ingrese el nombre a modificar:"<<endl;
            cin>>person.name;
            cout<<"Ingrese la nueva Direccion"<<endl;
            cin>>person.address;
            cout<<"Ingrese el Apellido Paterno a modificar"<<endl;
            cin>>person.father_name;
            cout<<"Ingrese el Apellido Materno a modificar"<<endl;
            cin>>person.mother_name;
            do{
            cout << "\nIngrese el numero nuevo: ";
            }while(scanf("%ld", &person.mobile_number) != 1);
            cout<<"Ingrese el nuevo Sexo: "<<endl;
            cin>>person.sex;
            cout<<"Ingrese el nuevo correo electronico: "<<endl;
            cin>>person.mail;
            cout<<"Ingrese el nuevo Numero ciudadano: "<<endl;
            cin>>person.citision_no;
            temp<<person.name<<" "<<person.address<<" "<<person.father_name<<" "<<person.mother_name<<" "<<person.mobile_number<<" "<<person.sex<<" "<<person.mail<<" "<<person.citision_no<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"Modificado"<<endl;
        }
          else
          {
            temp<<person.name<<" "<<person.address<<" "<<person.father_name<<" "<<person.mother_name<<" "<<person.mobile_number<<" "<<person.sex<<" "<<person.mail<<" "<<person.citision_no<<endl;
          }
              leer>>person.name>>person.address>>person.father_name>>person.mother_name>>person.mobile_number>>person.sex>>person.mail>>person.citision_no;
          }
          if(encontrado==false)
            {
              cout<<"Cedula no encontrada"<<endl;
            }
              leer.close();
              temp.close();
              remove("project.txt");
              rename("Temp.txt","project.txt");
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nota que en cada iteración únicamente estás intentando recuperar el nombre de la persona:

```
while(!leer.eof())
{
    leer>>person.name; // <<---
    cout<< person.name;
    if(person.name == nombre1)
```

Es decir, entiendo, viendo la siguiente línea:

```
leer >> person.name>>person.address>>person.father_name>>person.mother_name>>person.mobile_number>>person.sex>>person.mail>>person.citision_no;
```

que el archivo podría tener un formato tal que:

```
name0 address0 father_name0 ...
name1 address1 father_name1 ...
```

El compilador no se dedica a adivinar cuales son tus intenciones, si únicamente lees un string, el programa acabará comparando todos los campos con el nombre buscado:

```
if( name0 == nombre1 )
if( address0 == nombre1 )
if( father_name0 == nombre1 )
if( name1 == nombre1 )
// ...
```

No creo que sea esa tu intención, así que tienes que procurar leer el registro completo para comparar valores que tengan sentido:

```
leer.open("project.txt");//abre fichero original
// Aqui no leemos nada, o perderemos el primer registro

while(!leer.eof())
{
    leer >> person.name
         >> person.address
         >> person.father_name
         >> person.mother_name
         >> person.mobile_number
         >> person.sex
         >> person.mail
         >> person.citision_no;

    cout<< person.name;
    if(person.name == nombre1)
```

Comment: ohh entiendo bro